# What classifies a band as "indie"?

Tags: genre, indie

Is "indie" a moniker that indicates their record company is of a certain size, or not part of a larger music conglomerate, or is it a style or subgenre? Googling this seems to come up with multiple conflicting answers. In the world of film, studios have "indie film" divisions - is the same true for large record companies?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Originally the term 'Indie' was a shortened form of 'Independent', as in not tied to a major record label.

Of course, over the years, 'Indie' has become a genre of music so now refers to a style of music rather than the record labels that independent artists appear on.

> Independent music (often shortened to indie music or indie) is music produced independently from major commercial record labels or their subsidiaries, a process that may include an autonomous, do-it-yourself approach to recording and publishing. The term indie is sometimes also used to describe a genre (such as indie rock, indie metal or indie pop); as a genre term, "indie" may include music that is not independently produced, and most independent music artists do not fall into a single, defined musical style or genre and usually create music that can be categorized into other genres.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_music